# Keeps on redirecting on my development copy

Tags: redirect, https

I'm working on some edits for a client's site. So I downloaded the site's files and exported the database.

I need to make some big changes on a development machine first so I won't mess with the live site.

Then I imported the database to my development machine and setup the files as well. But whenever I go to http://localhost it redirects me to the client's site:
https://theclientsite.com

So since it redirects me to a https address I'm thinking it probably has something to do with that.

I did a global search on the code for the client's domain, but I don't see anything that redirects.

What could be the source of the redirecting? If the site doesn't stop redirecting, I can't work.

Comment: Is there any evidence that this redirect is **WordPress** related?

Comment: I asked my client if he installed any plugin that would do that and he said no.

Comment: there is no .htaccess file either

Answer (score 3):

Usually, this is a problem with the Site URL or WordPress URL not being set properly.  If you just copied the database, WordPress itself will try to redirect the domain back to what it thinks is the right site.

You have two options:

**1. Edit the Settings**

Use PHPMyAdmin or a similar tool to edit the site url and WordPress url settings in the database.  This *should* fix the problem assuming nothing else on your development box is forcing the redirect.

**2. Change your Hosts File**

This is the better solution.  Edit your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) to point `http://clientsite.com` at your local IP address (127.0.0.1).  Then, just navigate to the *development* site the same way you would the *production* site.  Just remember to change your hosts file back when you're done developing.

Comment: just edited the database for both the siteurl and home options. i'm going to try the hosts file solution now

Comment: ok, i edited my hosts file and it did work, the site is not redirected anymore, but now the links don't work, i can only see the homepage. i know it has something to do with permalinks because i go to http://domain.com/tour and i get a 404 not found error

Comment: The first solution sounds like the best one here. Editing your hosts file for dev if it's not necessary can cause confusion about which version you're actually viewing at any given time. If you're not careful, it may even cause you to make configuration changes on production when you think you're editing locally :S Plus, you have to re-edit your hosts file, clear your DNS cache, etc to switch view different deployment states, which can be a hassle.

Comment: @leonel Sounds like you're missing your .htaccess file. Make sure it's in the site's root, and that it has the "pretty permalink" rewrite rules in it.

Comment: If you're getting 404s from that kind of link, you're missing `.htaccess`  Log in and navigate to the Permalinks page and WP should auto-generate the file.

Comment: @MathSmath Editing your hosts file is one of the most often recommended solutions due to the way WP serializes data containing the site URL. Knowing which version you're on (production vs development) is a user issue.

Comment: @EAMann I know it's a common practice, but IMO it leaves a lot of room for developer error, and is a but of hassle to keep up with. An alternative that I find works perfectly (and avoids the serialization issue) is to use URLs of the same length for each deployment context. For example, use www.dot for production, stg.dot for staging and loc.dot for local. Then, when you find/replace the domain, serialization isn't an issue. Of course, everybody has their own way of doing things, but this has worked really well for me in cases where I'm not using a subdomain. YMMV. Either way, good answer!

Answer (score 3):

I concur with EAMann that it is probably database-related. I, however, think the first solution is better than the second of the two provided. When I move WordPress installations (usually from development to production rather than the opposite, like you), I simply run a few UPDATE statements in phpMyAdmin. This is what I run:

```
update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content,'development.org','production.org');
update wp_posts set guid = replace(guid,'development.org','production.org');
update wp_options set option_value = replace(option_value,'development.org','production.org');
update wp_commentmeta set meta_value = replace(meta_value,'development.org','production.org');
```

Make sure you edit the URLs and table names according to your situation.

Comment: It's annoying, but this is the correct answer; it's best to update all these table fields. I'd suggest making a script to do this.

Comment: Just be careful when running a search-replace on the database of a wordpress site.  Many fields are `serialized`, which means that the number of characters in those fields is stored with the data.  If you change the number of characters in a field, without also changing the *indicated* number of characters for that field, then that data is considered corrupt, and can break parts of your site.  So just make sure none of the fields to be updated contain serialization data.  Or use a plugin that handles serialized data. The `wp-cli search-replace` command line tool also handles serialization.

Comment: I never had problems with this, but sure. A comment above also pointed out the same thing back in 2012; along with a solution: have the same number of characters in development and production hostnames :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're into [wp-cli.org](https://wp-cli.org) this will do the trick in many cases:

```
wp search-replace example.com dev.example.com
```

Or if you're on `localhost`:

```
wp search-replace example.com localhost
```